# eclipse Neon : Error creating bean with name sessionFactory when run jUnit test file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I search in other threads here with this problem, but have not found the solution. Therefore, I'm forced to ask more specifically in another question.

I've a J2EE project, with Spring and Hibernate, managed by Maven and pom.xml
Borned on Eclipse Mars. Before I update to Eclipse Neon, jUnit test runs without problems.  In these days I need to update to Eclipse Neon: here starts my problem with jUnit tests: it's impossible to start the test, because when I choose a test file and "Run as jUnit test" obtain this error:

```
11:39:42,634 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:39:42,634 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
11:39:42,696 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
11:39:42,696 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
11:39:42,696 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to INFO
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework] to false
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework]
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.security] to ERROR
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.security] to false
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework.security]
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [it.pro] to ERROR
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [it.pro] to false
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[it.pro]
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.type] to ERROR
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.hibernate.type] to false
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.hibernate.type]
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:39:42,696 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5cb9f472 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:42 INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:42 INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6a79c292, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@37574691, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@25359ed8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@21a947fe, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@5606c0b, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@80ec1f8]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:42 INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-test.xml]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:43 INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-test.xml]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:43 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:43 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:43 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$CompositeUriComponentsContributorFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$CompositeUriComponentsContributorFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:43 INFO  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@2ea6137: startup date [Tue Dec 06 11:39:43 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=transactionalEventListenerFactory,declaringClass=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [app.properties]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [app.properties]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 INFO  o.s.s.a.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - No TaskExecutor bean found for async annotation processing.
dic 06, 2016 11:39:44 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFORMAZIONI: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
dic 06, 2016 11:39:44 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [application-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
SIGA - 2016-12-06 11:39:44 ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6a79c292] to prepare test instance [it.pro.test.integration.document.reports.FormularioReportTest@e93f3d5]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [application-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:110) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:309) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

The pom.xml is unchanged. The application-test.xml is unchanged (same of application.xml of project).

A colleague with the same environment, the same configuration (just downloaded from the repository) but with Eclipse Mars, run all the tests without problems.
Another colleague with my same environment (Eclipse Neon), the same configuration (just downloaded from the repository)...has my exactly problem.

Why jUnit (and Spring) give me that error on Eclipse Neon? 
I'm going crazy ... there is something to configure additional way in eclipse neon for testing?

**Due to chars limit, cutted a lot, This is the POM.XML**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<properties>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> -->

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <servletapi.version>3.1.0</servletapi.version>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- Query DSL -->
    <querydsl.version>4.0.9</querydsl.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.191</h2.version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.2</quartz.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <!-- 1. exclude commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
        <version>${servlet.version}</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <!-- 2. Bridge logging from JCL to SLF4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.rc2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/**/*.java</include>
                    <include>backend/**/*.java</include>
                    <include>model/**/*.java</include>
                    <include>batch/**/*.java</include>
                    <include>generated/**/*.java</include>
                    <include>test/java/**/*.java</include>  
                    <include>reports/**/*.java</include>                     
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>/target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin></plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Post your pom.xml, looks like a version mismatch error.

Comment: posted pom.xml. I have to cut some pieces due to chars limit 30000, but I've cutted not relevant pieces.

Comment: I hope you have not included any other version of hibernate jar in your classpath, If you are using eclipse  check if you have any external hierbnate jars added in your classpath/buildpath.
Do once "mvn clean install" and then try

Comment: I've done an "mvn clean install -DskipTests" but situation is the same. No other version of hibernate in project...I repeat that the pom and other configuration are the same in both enviroment (Mars or Neon) but in Neon tests don't work  :(

Comment: I just downloaded hibernate-core 5.1.final jar and decompiled it.
I can see that the method "applyClassLoader" is there.


  public BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder applyClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader)
  }
  
This looks like to be version issue only. Search your pc for all kind of hibernate jars and see if any jar is not being accidentally picked up>
You can use the tool "Search Everything" from web, it quickly searches anything in your pc.